# is it always bad to have Using temporary and filesort?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a situation where I specify up to 100 primary keys in where clause.

An example query:

```
select  product_id, max(date_created) AS last_order_date
    from  orders
    where  product_id=28906
      or  product_id=28903
      or  product_id=28897
      or  product_id=28848
      or  product_id=28841
      or  product_id=28839
      or  product_id=28838
      or  product_id=28837
      or  product_id=28833
      or  product_id=28832
      or  product_id=28831
      or  product_id=28821
      or  product_id=28819
      or  product_id=28816
      or  product_id=28814
      or  product_id=28813
      or  product_id=28802
      or  product_id=28800
      or  product_id=28775
      or  product_id=28773
    group by  product_id
    order by  date_created desc
```

EXPLAIN shows `Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort`

I'm aware that I should avoid a query with `Using temporary; Using filesort`, but do I have to avoid it even if the query execution time is fast even for a large dataset? I've given a list of IDs, so that query is the best I can do.

What side effects or disadvantages should I expect if I decide to continue using the query?

Explain output:

```
1   SIMPLE  wc_order_product_lookup range   product_id  product_id  8   NULL    3   Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? The newer versions now include the operator Index Skip Scan (imported from Oracle) that can be very fast for these kind of cases. Do the columns `product_id` and `date_created` partcipate in an index?

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm testing it on both MySQL 5.6 and MariaDB 10.3.3. I have index for both fields. Updated post with EXPLAIN out.

Comment: Ah... none of those have the new operator. I think it's one of the latest version of MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what Gordon says, but use

```
ORDER BY last_order_date DESC
```

`order by date_created desc` does not make sense.

It *may* switch to a table scan if the list is "too long".  This *may* be a difference in `EXPLAIN` between MySQL and MariaDB.  (The resultsets will be identical.)

If you do `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`, you may find that there are two filesorts.

Back to your original question...

"filesort" and "using temporary" are necessary in some cases -- especially like your case.  After it `GROUPs` the results, the `ORDER BY` calls for sorting in a way that was not specified by the `GROUP BY`.  This *necessitates* storing the data and sorting it.

"FILEsort" is a misnomer.  In *most* cases, the rows are sitting in RAM and can be very quickly sorted.  For very large resultsets and other complex situations, a "temporary" "file" will actually be used.

The Optimizer turns your list of `ORs` into an `IN` like Gordon's answer.  So, there is essentially no difference between the two ways of writing it.  (I find `IN` to be cleaner and more concise.)

`Using index condition` means that InnoDB is taking on some of the work that the generic "Handler" normally does.  (This is good, but not a big deal.)  However, replacing `INDEX(product_id)` by `INDEX(product_id, date_created)` is likely to be even better because it is "covering", which will be indicated by `Using index`.

"I have index for both fields" -- That is *not* the same as the composite index I am recommending.

You say "100 primary keys", but I suspect you mean "secondary" keys.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders` to discuss this.

I disagree with the old wives' tale: "should avoid a query with Using temporary; Using filesort".  Those are just clues that you are doing something that needs such complexity.  It can rarely be "avoided".

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Yes, you're right. It's a secondary key. Unfortunately, I have no option to create a new index in this case. I don't have a control over it.

Comment: @Moon - "No option"?  Even if a 3rd party product is trying to control MySQL, I would expect you to still be able to reach around and do `ALTER TABLE ... ADD INDEX ...`

Answer (score 1):

The filesort is being used for the `group by` or the `order by`.  It is pretty hard to avoid.  You might find that `in`, though, helps with the `where` clause:

```
select product_id,  max(date_created)  AS last_order_date
from orders
where product_id in (28906, 28903, 28897, . . . )
group by product_id
order by date_created desc;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. What side effect or cons do I have if I continue using it? The execution time is very fast for my use case. I'm just trying to see if there are any other unknown slow downs.

Comment: @Moon . .. It sounds like your query is already using an index on the product ids.  If you don't have too many row per product, the query should have pretty good performance,

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff. Given this is used in a REST API with a limited # of dataset, I think this is going to be fine.